# Deallocated instance | "Malloc_history cannot examine process XYZ because the process does not exist."

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, dealloc, malloc-history

I have memory problem (yes ;) I am new to iOS) with the following method in a custom UIView:

Header file

```
....    
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * pressureTextLabel;
....
```

Implementation draws a circle and a label with the pressure associated to the touch. Every finger touch creates a object of this view:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)theRect{
    CGRect rect = self.bounds;
    CGRect ringRect = CGRectInset(rect, 100, 100);

    // Outer ring.
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:ringRect];
    ringRect = CGRectInset(rect, 60, 60);
    [path appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:ringRect]];
    path.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;
    [self.color set];
    [path fill];

    //text label
    rect = CGRectMake(100, 20, 100, 100);

    //This one seems to be the troublemaker
    [pressureTextLabel drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];

}
```

all works fine as long as this following method is not called by the controller to update the sensed pressure for this particular touch.

```
-(void) setTouchPressureTo: (float) pressure{

    pressureTextLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", pressure];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

I get the following error:

```
*** -[CFString drawInRect:withFont:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x16e8c0
```

which made me investigate the memory trace in the debug console once the application crashed: `shell malloc_history <PID> 0x17dfb0` . As result the console returns:

`malloc_history cannot examine process 5838 because the process does not` exist.

**So here the question:**

1. Can someone see the obvious retain,
   release problem here?
2. How can I get `malloc_history <PID>
   <Address`>
       working?

Thank you for your time, redirects and answers!

Christian

Comment: If you run the app in the debugger, the process will stick around after the crash and you can run malloc_history on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're assigning an autoreleased object (your `[NSString stringWithFormat...]`) to an ivar (`pressureTextLabel`). You should be using property access instead, as in `self.pressureLabel = ...`.

Comment: Thank you Kevin! by using self it works but I have not quite understood why my code cause the problem or why your solved it.

Comment: You may want to read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)